# UIView with container and UITableView: no scroll indicator

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I made a view with a dynamic tableView and a container (that appears to add items in table). The view class complies with `UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource` and others. Table View has `showsVerticalScrollIndicator` and `scrollEnabled` on.

The interface is built with Interface Builder. Container is managed with segue and separate class, that has only one line: `@IBOutlet weak var containerTextField: UITextField!` in body, so it seems not to interfere with scroll indicators of the main view somehow.

But scroll indicator is not displayed, even when `flashScrollIndicators()` fires. Please, give me a hint, what could go wrong?

**Upd.** My bad. I meant a **vertical indicator** instead of a horizontal one. Casual vertical scroll indicator, that is also enabled in the Table View properties list.

**Upd2.** Screenshot: there is a container view with a text field right under the navigation bar. Screenshot taken on scroll, yet no vertical indicator visible.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Table views scroll vertically, not horizontally, and you won't see scroll indicators until there is more than one screen of content - can you include screenshots so it is easier to understand what is happening here?

Comment: or probably your scroll indicators is out of screen, check the tableview frame...

Comment: Scroll indicator appear only when you are scrolling the content else it will flash and hide.